# Robot optimization

Tags: optimization, atomic-code-golf

**Your task** is to program a robot so that it reaches the hole in the ground on each of the maps within reasonable time. If the robot reaches the hole, it falls down into it and thus victory is assured, even if the program never stops running.

Since the robot has to be programmed by manually punching in ones and zeroes, you want to solve the problems using as few commands as possible. Labels are translated to positions by the assembler and integrated into the `gotoblocked` and `call` commands, so the programmer never has to punch them into the robot. Therefore, they do not count towards the score. If the robot tries to move into a wall or off the map, nothing happens.

**The language** consists of these statements:

- `forward` move the robot forward one step
- `right` rotate 90 degrees clockwise
- `left` rotate 90 degrees counter-clockwise
- `for X {A1 A2 .. An}` repeat commands `A1, A2, ..., An` `X` times
- `call X` call a subroutine, beginning at label X
- `return` return from the subroutine
- `gotoblocked X` jump to label X if there is a wall immediately in front of the robot
- `mylabel:` a label used by `call` and/or `gotoblocked`. Loops may not contain any labels. Labels may only contain letters.

**The input** files consist of:
`testcase_name`
`N` `M`
and then an `N` by `M` grid of:

- `.` empty square
- `#` blocked square
- `M` the hole in the ground that we want to end up in
- `<` `>` `^` `v` starting position of the robot, directed left, right, up or down, respectively.

**The maps** can be found at http://progolymp.se/uploads/robot.zip

Your task is to solve all the maps.

**Validation:** 
The code you submit will be executed against all the test cases, starting at the label `testcasename` for each map. Follow the formatting in the example program.

**Scoring:**
The score is the number of statements (excluding labels) in the whole file, i.e. the code used to solve all testcases. Code reuse between testcases is ok.

**Example program** with starting points for testcases `robot_cross` and `robot_maze` (that solves neither):

```
walkandreturn:
  for 100 {
    forward
  }
robotmaze:
  gotoblocked done
  right
  right
  for 100 {
    for 3 {
      forward
    }
  }
done:
  return

robotcross:
  for 100 {
    call walkandreturn
    right
  }
```

**Automated judge** can be found at http://progolymp.se/uploads/robot.jar. 
To test a file against the testcase `robot_ew_manuell`, add this to the end of your program file:

```
main:
  call robotewmanuell
```

The judge starts execution at the label main, but we want it to start at `robotmaze` instead. This causes the judge to jump to where it should start, and saves me from having to write a new judge.

The actual judge can then be run like this:
`java -cp robot.jar parser.Runner robot_ew_manuell.in < my_solution.ans`

**Help wanted**
If you have a good place to mirror the files, or a way to post them on the site, please do.

This problem is based on the final problem of the 2016 online qualifier of Programmeringsolympiaden. https://po.kattis.com/problems/robotoptimering The original problem was authored by Johan Sannemo and Anton Grensjö. [CC BY-SA licensed](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), just like Stack Exchange.

Comment: Pretty sure this is just going to involve implementing A* (or similar) in your custom robolang.

Comment: @Draco18s How would you implement A* in this language? By using the robot to simulate a turing machine? Keep in mind that the challenge is to use as few statements as possible. Writing the commands one-by-one to take the robot from start to finish would probably use less statements.

Comment: Ah, there are specific test cases, no general case solution needed.  Never mind then.

Comment: You could write a single solution that handles all the test cases if you want to.

Comment: Yes, but it would handle *only those cases.*  It wouldn't handle *every possible case.*  That was my misunderstanding

Comment: Does the interpreter for this language implement comments?

Comment: Or are non-keywords ignored?

Comment: You can use labels for comments, without ever jumping to them. Non-keywords shouldn't be in the code.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I stumbled upon it and have a question: Can labels be nested inside for-loops, and what happens if those labels are jumped to?

Comment: @R.M You're allowed to jump to labels in the currently running loop, in which case the loop counter doesn't change, or to a label in any outer loop if you've nested them, since you're technically in that loop as well.

Comment: So you can jump outside a loop, but can't jump inside a loop, did I understand correctly?

Comment: @R.M Exactly. You can jump around within the same loop iteration, or break out of any number of loops.